# Java enum class

Tags: java, oop, enums

I am implementing the enum class which I will use to retrieve some background in application,
a current implementation of this class is here:

```
public enum Painters{

    /**
     * Available painters.
     */
    Background(getBackgroundPainter()),
    InactiveBackground(getInactiveBackgroundPainter()),
    DesktopBackground(getBackgroundPainter());

    /**
     * The background painter.
     */
    private Painter<Component> _painter;

    /**
     * Constructor will initialize the object.
     */
    Painters(Painter<Component> painter){
        _painter = painter;
    }

    /**
     * Will return a current painter.
     * @return instance of Painter<Component>
     */
    public Painter<Component> painter(){
        return _painter;
    }

    private static Painter<Component> getBackgroundPainter(){
        MattePainter mp = new MattePainter(Colors.White.alpha(1f));
        PinstripePainter pp = new PinstripePainter(Colors.Gray.alpha(0.2f),45d);
       return (new CompoundPainter<Component>(mp, pp)); 
    }

    private static Painter<Component> getInactiveBackgroundPainter(){
        MattePainter mp = new MattePainter(Colors.White.alpha(1f));
        GlossPainter gp = new GlossPainter(Colors.Gray.alpha(0.1f), GlossPainter.GlossPosition.BOTTOM);
        PinstripePainter pp = new PinstripePainter(Colors.Gray.alpha(0.2f), 45d);
        return (new CompoundPainter<Component>(mp, pp, gp));    
    }
}
```

My problem is that I need to call the painter() method each time I trying to get a painter but I prefer just to write the type of the painter instead. I thought that if I can to extend the Painter by my enum then probably I will get the right functionality, but it looks that it is not possible in java.

```
public enum Painters extends Painter<Component>
```

Do you know any solution for this problem???

Currently I am using it in this way:

```
Painters.Background.painter();
```

but I need:

```
Painters.Background;
```

Comment: I think you selected the wrong answer as "correct".

Comment: Actually my painter is already an interface I confused with it because it was without I in the beginning ( Painter in my case is swingx's painter ). I believe that the answer is right in any case because the enum class allows to implement the interface and this is the only way to implement what do I need.

Comment: I did it with a factory before but I decided that enum class would be more elegant solution.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels - how is an answer that avoids the question more correct than one that proposes a working solution?

Comment: I'm sure you've seen situations where the question asks for a kludge to fix a design problem where the true solution is to fix the design issue. Factory seems a more natural fit here (at least to me).

Comment: Interesting but it looks just like another way to implement the factory in java, without using the switch -> if else. In my opinion it is just more elegant way to implement a factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always define your painter as an interface and have your enum implement it. You won't be able to use generic wildcards, but as long as thats not a constraint you will be able to reference the painter in code the way you are wanting too:

```
interface Painter<T> {
    // ...
}

public enum Painters implements Painter<Component> {
    Background(getBackgroundPainter()),
    InactiveBackground(getInactiveBackgroundPainter()),
    DesktopBackground(getBackgroundPainter());

    private Painter<Component> _painter;

    // ...
}

Painter somePainter = Painters.Background;
```

Your enum would effectively be proxying over actual painter implementations.

Answer (score 2):

Typically `Enums` are reserved for immutable constants where you need the the syntactic sugar of the switch/case and constructors.  A factory pattern is more appropriate here:

```
public class PainterFactory {
    public static Painter<Component> getBackgroundPainter(){
    ...
    }

    public static Painter<Component> getInactiveBackgroundPainter(){
    ...
    }
}
```